# @ symbol before php function

Tags: php

I'm don't understand what mean `@` symbol before php function for example: `@mysql_query()`, if someone know please explain for me.

Comment: its is used to suppress PHP Error

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's the [error suppression operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), normally not a good idea to use it as you should be trapping errors cleanly rather than simply hiding them

Answer (score 7):

It will silent error messages. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 3):

It means that if an error is generated by that function, it is not shown. It suppresses the error so to say. As the PHP manual states:

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
>   generated by that expression will be ignored.

Look here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php